# error using pdo in php

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I've tried the following script in php:

```
$prod_no = " SELECT no FROM e_produit WHERE nom LIKE '%NAVIGATOR%' ";
$stmt = $pdo->query($prod_no);
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $row;
```

But I get the error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string.
```

Comment: What is the question though? This code throws pretty expected error.

Comment: Just print the `$row` you will know what it will return

Answer (score 1):

> **Object** of class PDOStatement **could not be converted to string.**

Meaning, you cannot `echo $row`, because `$row` isn't a string.

#### Debug:

`print_r($row, true)`

#### Nice print:

`echo $row['no'];`

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

"*PDO::FETCH_ASSOC: Return next row as an array indexed by column name*"

Comment: I like to use `var_debug($row)` or [var_export](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php)

Comment: Yeah, me too, depending on what information I want :)